# How to build new object using keys from array of keys and values from another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have this array of keys:

`["newId", "newFirstName", "newLastName"]`

and i have also array of objects that looks like this:

`[{"oldId":1,
   "oldFirstName":"name1",
   "oldLastName":"lastName1",
    ...not impotent data
  },
  {
   "oldId":2,
   "oldFirstName":"name2",
   "oldLastName":"lastName2",
   ...not impotent data
  }]`

I want result of this array:

`[{"newId":1,
   "newFirstName":"name1",
   "newLastName":"lastName1",
  },
  {
   "newId":2,
   "newFirstName":"name2",
   "newLastName":"lastName2",
  }]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can be sure that the order of `old` keys in your object will never change and *there will never be a key missing*, then you can do something like this:

```js
const newKeys = ['newId', 'newFirstName', 'newLastName']

const transform = obj => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj)
    .slice(0, newKeys.length)
    .map(([key, value], index) => [newKeys[index], value])
)

const oldArray = [
  {
    oldId: 1,
    oldFirstName: 'A',
    oldLastName: 'B',
    unimportant: 'x'
  },
  {
    oldId: 2,
    oldFirstName: 'C',
    oldLastName: 'D',
    unimportant: 'x'
  }
]

const newArray = oldArray.map(transform)

console.log(newArray)
/* Result:
[
  {
    newId: 1,
    newFirstName: 'A',
    newLastName: 'B'
  },
  {
    newId: 2,
    newFirstName: 'C',
    newLastName: 'D'
  }
]
*/
```

What `transform` does:

- It turns the data from the form `{oldId: 1, oldFirstName: 'A', oldLastName: 'B', unimportant: 'x'}` into `[['oldId', 1], ['oldFirstName', 'A'], ['oldLastName', 'B'], ['unimportant', 'x']]` using `Object.entries`, so that we can use array methods on it.
- It cuts off any entries beyond the number of "new keys" specified using `slice`, so that the "unimportant data" won't get processed, so `[['oldId', 1], ['oldFirstName', 'A'], ['oldLastName', 'B'], ['unimportant', 'x']]` becomes `[['oldId', 1], ['oldFirstName', 'A'], ['oldLastName', 'B']]`.
- It `map`s all the entries from `[key, value]` to `[newKey, value]`, looking up `newKey` from the `newKeys` array based on the *index* of the current entry (the how-many-th it is in the object), so `[['oldId', 1], ['oldFirstName', 'A'], ['oldLastName', 'B']]` becomes `[['newId', 1], ['newFirstName', 'A'], ['newLastName', 'B']]`.
- It turns the modified data from the form `[['newId', 1], ['newFirstName', 'A'], ['newLastName', 'B']]` back into the structure `{newId: 1, newFirstName: 'A', newLastName: 'B'}` using `Object.fromEntries`.

At the end we just call this transformation on all elements of your array using `map`.

Note: If your ECMAScript version doesn't have `Object.fromEntries`, you can use a polyfill: `Object.fromEntries = a => a.reduce((o, [k, v]) => Object.assign(o, { [k]: v }), {})`

Comment: Great explanation thank you